# VS Code is not starting without internet

Tags: visual-studio-code, startup, offline-mode

last few days I was getting frustrated due to a problem in vs code. last month I switched from atom to vs code. Everything was working fine until yesterday.

I was working on a project , after finishing half of the project I just closed the editor and went for a walk then I came back and I took my laptop to continue my work. that time there was a problem with the internet modem so I disconnected internet from my laptop then I try to run vs code. from that moment vs code was not launching, I try to run it has administrator, I tried with compatibility issues but nothing worked. but once I connect it to internet it was working perfectly.

I have two questions:

1. Does VS Code require internet to work?
2. If it is a bug can any one please help.

Comment: Vs code should work offline - I looked around and googled it and it seems like a lot of people have also had this problem. Have you tried turning off the wi-fi and then turning it back on? Usually works for me.

Comment: I tried it. Not working:-(

Comment: both vscode and atom has the same problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a extension issue. I have the same problem and have PHP and other web extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is supposed to provide basic editing features without needing an internet connection. When you use VS Code with a network connection, the hosts it makes communications with can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network).

Looking at the date this was posted, I'm guessing you had VS Code 1.29.x, 1.30.x, or similar installed. Googling "`vscode 1.29 cannot start without internet connection`" leads to 
[VS Code does not launch after update 1.29.1 when offline.
#63658](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63658), which points to the underlying issue being to do with Electron (see [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6437)) and to [VS Code doesn't launch without internet
#68274](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68274), which is closed as a duplicate pointing to [VS Code fails to start/open when offline
#7570](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7570). The TL;DR of that issue thread is found [here in a comment by @wildapt01](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7570#issuecomment-461230482):

> This is fixed. Upgrade VSC to 1.31 February 2019 release. VSC runs now on Electron 3.

I think they meant to say *January 2019* and not February. [Here are the release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31). You can even see #7570 listed in [the "Notable fixes" section](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_notable-fixes).

Comment: not that this helps anyone, since we're _way_ past 1.29 and 1.30 now, but here it is for any future historians who care for some reason.